# Create a existing SQL table valued function to Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, function

I have a table valued function created in SQL that gives me a list of values for each month based upon the dates passed as parameters. It works fine when I execute in SQL server but I need to create a similar function in Oracle as well. I am not familiar with Oracle code so could anyone please help in letting me know how to convert the function into an oracle function??
The function in SQL is as follows :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ES_REPORT_PSH_FISCALANALYSIS_FUNCTION]
(@P_AUTHORITY VARCHAR (100) = '',
 @P_STARTDATE DATETIME = '',
 @P_ENDDATE DATETIME = '',
 @P_CLOSEDREASONS VARCHAR (100) = '',
 @P_GRANTTYPES VARCHAR (100) = '')

RETURNS @RETURNTABLE TABLE(GRTYPE VARCHAR(100),
GRTYPEDESC          VARCHAR(200),
TASK                VARCHAR(100),
TASKDESC            VARCHAR(100),
PERIODTEXT          VARCHAR(100),
COUNT_DTRECD        INT,
COUNT_DTSCHD        INT,
COUNT_DTAPLMADE     INT,
COUNT_DTAPPR        INT,
COUNT_DTCMPLTD      INT,
COUNT_DTCLOSED      INT,
SUM_GRANTVALUE      MONEY,
VAL_PAYMENTS        MONEY)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RETURNTABLE_1 TABLE
(
GRTYPE              VARCHAR(100),
GRTYPEDESC          VARCHAR(200),
TASK                VARCHAR(100),
TASKDESC            VARCHAR(100),
PERIODTEXT          VARCHAR(100),
COUNT_DTRECD        INT,
COUNT_DTSCHD        INT,
COUNT_DTAPLMADE     INT,
COUNT_DTAPPR        INT,
COUNT_DTCMPLTD      INT,
COUNT_DTCLOSED      INT,
SUM_GRANTVALUE      MONEY,
VAL_PAYMENTS        MONEY
)

--populate default values;
declare @tmpDate DATETIME
declare @perText VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @GTT_SPLIT_VALUES TABLE(ROW INT, VALUE VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @GTT_SPLIT_VALUES SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ROW,VAL FROM [DBO].[SPLITVALUES](@P_GRANTTYPES, ',')
DECLARE @counter INT = 1
DECLARE @max INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @GTT_SPLIT_VALUES)
DECLARE @thisGR VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @thisGR1 VARCHAR(100)

WHILE @counter <= @max
BEGIN
  SET @thisGR = (SELECT VALUE FROM @GTT_SPLIT_VALUES where ROW = @Counter)
  SET @thisGR1 = (SELECT TOP 1 TASKDESC FROM PPV_GRANTS pv1 LEFT JOIN @GTT_SPLIT_VALUES pv on pv.VALUE = pv1.TASK where ROW = @Counter)
  SET @tmpDate = @P_STARTDATE
  WHILE (@tmpDate < @P_ENDDATE)
  BEGIN
    SET @perText = DATENAME(month, @tmpDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(year, @tmpDate) 
    INSERT INTO @RETURNTABLE select @thisGR,@thisGR,@thisGR,@thisGR1,@perText,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from dual
    SET @tmpDate = DATEADD(month, 1, @tmpDate)
  END
  SET @counter = @counter + 1
  
END

--logic in here
declare crGrants CURSOR for select PG.GRTYPE, PG.GRTYPEDESC,PG.TASK,PG.TASKDESC, PG.DTRECD, PG.DTSCHD, PG.DTAPLMADE, PG.DTAPPR, PG.DTCMPLTD,PG.DTCLOSED,PG.GRANTVALUE,PGP.VALUE,PGP.PAYMENTDATE
                            from dbo.PPV_GRANTS PG
                            LEFT JOIN PPV_GRANT_PAYMENTS PGP ON PGP.WORKID = PG.WORKID
                            order by PG.WORKID

declare @GRTYPE VARCHAR(4)
declare @GRTYPEDESC VARCHAR(50)
declare @TASK VARCHAR(100)
declare @TASKDESC VARCHAR(100)
declare @DTRECD DATETIME
declare @DTSCHD DATETIME
declare @DTAPLMADE DATETIME
declare @DTAPPR DATETIME
declare @DTCMPLTD DATETIME
declare @DTCLOSED DATETIME
declare @MONTHTXT VARCHAR(20)
declare @GRANTVALUE FLOAT
declare @Value FLOAT
declare @PaymentDate DATETIME

open crGrants
FETCH NEXT FROM crGrants INTO @GRTYPE, @GRTYPEDESC,@TASK,@TASKDESC, @DTRECD, @DTSCHD, @DTAPLMADE, @DTAPPR, @DTCMPLTD, @DTCLOSED,@GRANTVALUE, @Value, @PaymentDate
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
  IF (@DTRECD >= @P_STARTDATE AND @DTRECD <= @P_ENDDATE)
  BEGIN
    SET @perText = DATENAME(month, @DTRECD) + ' ' + DATENAME(year, @DTRECD)
    UPDATE @RETURNTABLE SET COUNT_DTRECD = COUNT_DTRECD + 1 
    WHERE GRTYPE = @GRTYPE and PERIODTEXT = @perText
  END

   IF (@DTSCHD >= @P_STARTDATE AND @DTSCHD <= @P_ENDDATE)
  BEGIN
    SET @perText = DATENAME(month, @DTSCHD) + ' ' + DATENAME(year, @DTSCHD)
    UPDATE @RETURNTABLE SET COUNT_DTSCHD = COUNT_DTSCHD + 1 
    WHERE GRTYPE = @GRTYPE and PERIODTEXT = @perText
  END

   IF (@DTAPLMADE >= @P_STARTDATE AND @DTAPLMADE <= @P_ENDDATE)
  BEGIN
    SET @perText = DATENAME(month, @DTAPLMADE) + ' ' + DATENAME(year, @DTAPLMADE)
    UPDATE @RETURNTABLE SET COUNT_DTAPLMADE = COUNT_DTAPLMADE + 1 
    WHERE GRTYPE = @GRTYPE and PERIODTEXT = @perText
  END 

    IF (@DTAPPR >= @P_STARTDATE AND @DTAPPR <= @P_ENDDATE)
  BEGIN
    SET @perText = DATENAME(month, @DTAPPR) + ' ' + DATENAME(year, @DTAPPR)
    UPDATE @RETURNTABLE SET COUNT_DTAPPR = COUNT_DTAPPR + 1 
    WHERE GRTYPE = @GRTYPE and PERIODTEXT = @perText
  END

  IF (@DTCMPLTD >= @P_STARTDATE AND @DTCMPLTD <= @P_ENDDATE)
  BEGIN
    SET @perText = DATENAME(month, @DTCMPLTD) + ' ' + DATENAME(year, @DTCMPLTD)
    UPDATE @RETURNTABLE SET COUNT_DTCMPLTD = COUNT_DTCMPLTD + 1 
    WHERE GRTYPE = @GRTYPE and PERIODTEXT = @perText
  END

  IF (@DTCLOSED >= @P_STARTDATE AND @DTCLOSED <= @P_ENDDATE)
  BEGIN
    SET @perText = DATENAME(month, @DTCLOSED) + ' ' + DATENAME(year, @DTCLOSED)
    UPDATE @RETURNTABLE SET COUNT_DTCLOSED = COUNT_DTCLOSED + 1 
    WHERE GRTYPE = @GRTYPE and PERIODTEXT = @perText
  END

    IF (@DTAPPR >= @P_STARTDATE AND @DTAPPR <= @P_ENDDATE)
  BEGIN
    SET @perText = DATENAME(month, @DTAPPR) + ' ' + DATENAME(year, @DTAPPR)
    UPDATE @RETURNTABLE SET SUM_GRANTVALUE = @GRANTVALUE
    WHERE GRTYPE = @GRTYPE and PERIODTEXT = @perText
  END

IF (@PaymentDate >= @P_STARTDATE AND @PaymentDate <= @P_ENDDATE)
  BEGIN
    SET @perText = DATENAME(month, @PaymentDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(year, @PaymentDate)
    UPDATE @RETURNTABLE SET VAL_PAYMENTS = @Value 
    WHERE GRTYPE = @GRTYPE and PERIODTEXT = @perText
  END

   FETCH NEXT FROM crGrants INTO @GRTYPE, @GRTYPEDESC,@TASK,@TASKDESC, @DTRECD, @DTSCHD, @DTAPLMADE, @DTAPPR, @DTCMPLTD, @DTCLOSED , @GRANTVALUE , @Value , @PaymentDate

END
close crGrants
deallocate crGrants

--result set
RETURN
END
```

Comment: I can't lie, that function looks *horrific*. It's a Multi-line table value function, which are well known to perform terribly, and it has *two* `WHILE` loops, which are also well known to perform awfully. I would honestly rethink the solution in both Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: @Larnu AND a cursor which runs after while loops. A rewrite is definitely the best answer here.

Comment: I was counting the `CURSOR` as one of the `WHILE`s, @SeanLange , if I'm honest, as you (normally)*need* a `WHILE` to use one.

Comment: @Larnu there are two while loops before the cursor though. Regardless this needs some serious help. ;)

Comment: Oh god, @SeanLange , I didn't even see the `WHILE` *inside* the `WHILE`... 

Comment: @Larnu@Sean Lange I agree to what you say but the req was also such that I just had this option of creating a function which operates in such a way that i get this kind of result as attached

GRTYPE GRTYPEDESC TASK TASKDESC PERIODTEXT COUNT_DTRECD COUNT_DTSCHD COUNT_DTAPLMADE COUNT_DTAPPR COUNT_DTCMPLTD COUNT_DTCLOSED SUM_GRANTVALUE VAL_PAYMENTS
CP CP CP Common Parts April 2021 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.00 0.00
CP CP CP Common Parts May 2021 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.00 0.00

till the financial year. If we had data in the database for each month then it would have been much simpler but that's not the case here.

Comment: You still don't need loops for this kind of thing. This is where a numbers or tally table makes this a LOT easier to deal with. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1

Comment: The thing is, there is very likely a *set based* method to achieve what you want, in an inline table value function, @AdarshI . I would not be surprised if you see the performance of queries using that ml-TVF improve by minutes, or even hours, if you switched to an iTVF.

Comment: This question is very broad. Please read [ask] and strip this down to a specific issue you encoutered while translating from Transact-SQL to PL/SQL!

Comment: Whenever you have a question, please post a little sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for all tables involved, relevant columns only) so the people who want to help you can recreate the problem and test their ideas. Also post the exact results you want from that data, and explain why you want those results from that data. Always post your complete Oracle version (e.g. 18.4.0.0.0).